# Cause multiplication of incompatible types to throw error in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm doing some debugging right now, and the problem appears to be that two incompatible types (string and integer) are being multiplied together. Right now, when these are multiplied together, a NaN result is returned. I want to run the code in a mode such that when incompatible types are multiplied together, an error is thrown instead. I tried running the code in strict mode (`'use strict'`) but this did not work. How would I do this?

```
console.log(2*'a')
> NaN
```

Comment: You might want to look into [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) which would help with this kind of checking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throw your own error, and handle appropriately, eg:

```
try { 
    if(isNaN( 2*'a')) throw new Error("not a number");
}
catch(err) {
   // handle error here
}
```

Or check the type of the variable to handle appropriately, eg.

```
if (typeof(variableName) === "number")) {
    console.log('variable is a number');
} else {
    throw new Error('variable is NOT a number');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can't change Javascript's behavior with this.** The [ES6 spec is specific on how this behavior](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-multiplicative-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) works.

If possible, try to re-architect your code so a string can't be assigned to this variable in the first place. If that's not possible, checking for `NaN` manually as @yezzz suggests is the next best option.